# Customise ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would be grateful if someone could tell me how to modify the legend in the following plot:

```
  point_data <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                           y = rnorm(10),
                           type=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5)))

  line_data <- data.frame(x=c(-1,0),
                          y=c(1,0))

  ggplot(data=point_data,
         aes(x=x,
             y=y,
             colour=type)) +
    geom_point(size=0.75) +
    geom_line(data=line_data, 
              aes(x=x,y=y,colour="myline"))
```

[image]

I want to remove "myline" from the legend, and have only points next to "A" and "B".

Comment: Do you still want the third box in the legend but with just a line in it and no label or are you looking for a two box legend?

Comment: I would like a two box legend please.

Comment: Using geom_line(data=line_data, aes(x=x,y=y,colour="myline"),show.legend = FALSE) just removed the line from all three boxes in the legend. I find this counter intuitive, why does a call to geom_line() influence all of the items in the legend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move `data` and `aes()` to the `geom_point`and remove the `color=` from 
`geom_line` then you will have only "A" and "B" in the legend

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data=point_data, aes(x=x,
                 y=y,
                 color=type), size=0.75) +
  geom_line(data=line_data, 
            aes(x=x,y=y))
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain why that works please? How could I specify the colour of the line in this case without adding it to the legend?

Comment: @slabofguinness  If you still want to set the line color to a constant you can do so outside of `aes()` in `geom_line()`.  Like `color = "blue"`.